# how to get the file header size of tiff image

Tags: headers, tiff

how to get the file header size of tiff image?
I need this value for data processing.

Comment: Including the tags or just the header?

Comment: I guess it is just the header.

Comment: You want to use in in your program? Which language?

Comment: .OPERATION: CP FROM RAW
.EXISTING RAW FILE: INP000
[Enter name of input file.] 
.ENTER BITS / PIXEL IN INPUT IMAGE (8, 16, 32 or -32): 16
[Enter bits used for each pixel in input file. The 32 bit input is assumed to be floating point! An entry of -32 will read floating point data and flip the byte ordering to compensate for different "endedness" of data.] 
.ENTER COLUMNS, ROWS & SLICES: 64 64 64
[Enter columns, rows, and slices in input file.]

Comment: ENTER HEADER BYTES TO BE SKIPPED: 512
[Enter bytes in input file header that should be skipped.] 
If the input file has 16 bits / pixel the following two questions will appear. If you are unsure of the correct answers try all four possible combinations and examine the output images to see which one is correct:

Comment: http://www.wadsworth.org/spider_doc/spider/docs/man/cpfromraw.html

Answer (score 2):

The header is 8 bytes:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                            TIFF Header                                 |
+--------+-------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
| Offset | Type  | Default  | Description                                |
+--------+-------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
| 0-1    | WORD  | II or MM | Endian: Intel (little) / Motorola (big)    |
| 2-3    | WORD  | 0x2A     | Version (usually 42)                       |
| 4-7    | ULONG |          | Offset to first IFD (image file directory) |
+--------+-------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
```

Here’s several references:

- http://www.compix.com/fileformattif.htm
- http://www.fileformat.info/format/tiff/corion.htm
- http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/faq.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format